# Python: skip all lines without a letter/number

Tags: python

I couldn't find this asked anywhere, I'm kind of surprised. I'm trying to read in a huge file line-by-line using this:

```
with open("file.csv") as f:
    for line in f:
        splitline = line.split()
```

If I `print(splitline)`, I get many many lines with just commas, that I don't want:

```
[',,,,,,,']
```

Lines I do want look like:

```
['XZ02345,AAA,BBB,1.0,11.0,15.0,1.0,1.0']
```

I have tried all kinds of `if 'XZ' in splitline: print(splitline)` and `if splitline[0] == "": continue` type solutions, but anything I try either prints all lines or none.

Desired output is no lines that are just commas `[',,,,,,,']`

Comment: `if splitline != [',,,,,,,']:`...?

Comment: can you share your csv file?

Comment: can you share few lines of file.csv? To understand the question clearly

Comment: You are parsing the .csv file "by hand". Consider using the `csv` module.

Comment: Also, from what I see, `line.split()` is not serving any purpose here (considering the csv nature of the file). What exactly is the code trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `regex`

```
import re

with open("file.csv") as f:
    for line in f:
        if re.match(r'^\,*$', line) is None:
            splitline = line.split()
            print(splitline)
```

This tries to find string only with `,`, and if string has anything else, it processes the string

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with open("file.csv") as f:
    for line in f:
        if(re.sub('[^0-9a-zA-Z]+', '', str(line))):
            splitline = line.split()
```

Answer (score 0):

you got [',,,,,,,'] because you do not have data filled in the csv row

you could print if there is actual data:

```
delimiter = ','
if splitline.replace(delimiter, '').strip():
    print(splitline.split())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are really just interested if there are not only commas (which is different from your question title), you can use the following:

```
empty = True
for char in splitline[0]: 
    if char != ',':
        empty = False
        break

if empty:
   continue
```

Less verbose

```
if not any([char != ',' for char in splitline[0]]):
    continue
```

If it's really just about the exact pattern you should be able to use the comment from Aran-Fey :

```
if splitline == [',,,,,,,']:
    continue
```

Answer (score 0):

below split() function add condition if splitline.replace(',','') !='': to control the print to not print ,,,,,,, lines.

Comment: complete code : with open("file.csv") as f:
    for line in f:
        splitline = line.split()
        if splitline.replace(',','') !='':
            print(splitline)